# Solving a 2nd order non-linear ODE with Python?

Tags: odeint

My Equation that I'm trying to solve is of the form:

y''(t)=C*cos(y(t)) + D*sin(y(t))

y'(0)=45

y(0)=0

where C=0.2544 and D=2.544

How do I go about solving this? I am really just completely lost here, and I've tried everything I could. I'm really just confused on how to use the scipy odeint function as well. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!!!

Comment: What did you try? What did not work? Any samples? errors?

Comment: You're trying to get values of y at discreet values of t going from 0 up to some number (say 10) with a particular step size (say 0.1) correct?